# How to override the systemd default LogLevel

Tags: debian, systemd

When I look at the file `/etc/systemd/system.conf` I can see the following:

```
[Manager]
#LogLevel=info
#LogTarget=journal-or-kmsg
#LogColor=yes
#LogLocation=no
```

But if I run `systemctl show -pLogLevel` the result is

```
LogLevel=notice
```

I tried to create a directory named `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d` and to add a `my.conf` file inside and then rebooted, but couldn't see any change.

Am I looking at the right config file?

Comment: This question is off-topic - belongs in http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or [su]

Answer (score 0):

The dropin system configuration is relatively recently introduced. I believe you are running an old version of systemd.

I have tested your case on systemd 226 and things are working as expected.

```
$>:Development$ systemctl show -pLogLevel
LogLevel=info
$>:Development$ cat /etc/systemd/system.conf | grep LogLevel
#LogLevel=info
```